# How to delete all variables except an environment

Tags: r, r-environment

I would like to delete all global variables except a defined environment with variables in it.

Say I have the following:

```
my.env = new.env()
assign("a", 123, envir = my.env)
my.env$somestring = "Variable mat as vector string"
```

And also some global variables:

```
Age     <-  as.numeric(42)
HbA     <-  as.numeric(2)
WHR     <-  as.numeric(1.3)
```

I know I can delete all global variables but one with `setdiff`

```
setdiff(ls(),'Age')
#[1] "HbA"    "my.env" "WHR"
```

but when I call the following I get an error. This is expected because `my.env` is actually a pointer, if I am not mistaken

```
setdiff(ls(), my.env)
#Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
#  cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'any'
```

How can I delete all variables but keep `my.env`? (with the variables in it)

Comment: Have you tried to quote `my.env` like `setdiff(ls(), 'my.env')`?

Comment: That did it. Kinda stupid of me that I did not think of it this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
to.del <- setdiff(ls(), "my.env")
rm(list = to.del)

# not relevant anymore
eval(parse(text = paste0("rm(", to.del, ")")))
```

Comment: `rm` has a `list=` argument.

Comment: Right, completely forgot about it.